# JavaScript Cookie Sets array but does not return it

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using [JavaScript Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and I set the the cookie with a value of a blank array, but when i try to read te value, the return type is not an array. What am I doing wrong and why is it wrong?

```
if (Cookies.get('saved_boards') == null) {
    var array = new Array();
    Cookies.set('saved_boards', array, {
        expires: 1
    });
}

var saves = Cookies.get('saved_boards'); // saves is not of array type
```

Comment: Have you tried using an array literal over the array constructor?: `[]`

Comment: Cookies save string values. Your array is automatically coerced to a string when you try to save it. Try using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` so that you can store and retrieve JSON.  @CarlEdwards - that wouldn't make any difference, both create the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As @nnnnnn pointed out, the array was set to a string when set as the value of a cookie, therefore parsing is needed to get the response as an array.

```
var saves = Cookies.getJSON('saved_boards');
```

This method gets and parses the response in one step.